# What is a good alternative to Publisher for Desktop Publishing?

Tags: publishing, microsoft-publisher

On occasion, I have the need to design flyers, small newsletters, tri-fold brochures and other printed documents for my business or for civic groups I volunteer with.

In the past I have had access to Microsoft Publisher to create some of these things, but I am wondering if there is a better desktop publishing package out there for the small business and personal markets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**OpenOffice** or [Scribus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribus)

Both are open source

Comment: +1 for Scribus, especially since I've never heard of it before. I think it's closer to what Marshall is looking for, anyway.

Comment: +1 for both OpenOffice and Scribus: great programs, both free software (as in no cost and giving freedom of use to the user).

Comment: Is being open source the only reason they're better than Publisher?

Answer (score 5):

[Adobe InDesign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_InDesign) is a very popular desktop publishing program. It is more precise and feature rich than MS Publisher (as well as more expensive). If you find that Publisher is limiting and too basic for the work you do, InDesign is a good next step.

QuarkXPress used to be the program to beat. However, the company fired all their programmers and brought in cheap labor, and we all know how that turns out.

Comment: I agree that InDesign is far better than Publisher. Although InDesign is very expensive relative to Publisher (though one could argue that it is value for money, relatively), both to purchase and to keep current. However, Scribus and OpenOffice are both cost-free and, for many people (and perhaps all non-professional designers), provide all they need from a desktop publishing package.